# Why this code gives me error? is there self-mistake?

Tags: c++

You can check this code at *"Programing Principles Practice Using C++"* book page 348. there are no writing mistakes, I think there is an error using the same variable's name "**name"** or **code sequance order**.
when i'm running this code and asked me to enter file name one for input and other one for output, the program close without any effect or error.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

// struct Reading
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t) : hour(h), temperature(t) {}
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist(name.c_str()); // ist reads from the file named "name"

    if (!ist) 
        error("can't open input file ", name);

    cout << "Please enter name of output file: ";
    cin >> name;
    ofstream ost(name.c_str());

    if (!ost) 
        error("can't open output file ", name);

    vector<Reading> temps;
    int hour;
    double temperture;

    while (ist >> hour >> temperture) {
        if (hour < 0 || 23 < hour) 
            error("hour out of range", "While reading");            
        temps.push_back(Reading(hour, temperture));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i)
        ost << '(' << temps[i].hour << ',' << temps[i].temperature << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to indent your code correctly , it is hard to read

Comment: Was ist das: `while (ist >> hour >> temperture)`?

Comment: It's expected to just close after reading and writing. Don't you get an output file?

Comment: *"Why this code gives me error? [...] the program close without any effect or error"* So, is there an error now or not? Maybe put a `cout << "Success!" << endl;` at the end before the `return 0;` for debugging purposes if you're not sure...

Comment: You really need to explain clearly what happens, and what you expected to happen instead. Especially since it includes a non-standard header, so we can't compile it ourselves to see what happens.

Comment: @Bathsheba That repeatedly extracts formatted value-pairs from the input file.

Answer (score 0):

i changed statment sequence order, I typed:

```
vector<Reading> temps;
  int hour;
  double temperture;

while (ist >> hour >> temperture) {
    if (hour < 0 || 23 < hour) 
        error("hour out of range", "While reading");            
    temps.push_back(Reading(hour, temperture));
}
```

after this line of code...

```
if (!ist) 
    error("can't open input file ", name);
```

//// full version

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// struct Reading

struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t) : hour(h), temperature(t) {}
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist(name.c_str()); // ist reads from the file named "name"
    if (!ist) error("can't open input file ", name);  

    //why the book typed it here
    vector<Reading>temps;
    int hour;
    double temperture;
    while (ist >> hour >> temperture) {
        if (hour < 0 || 23 < hour) error("hour out of range", "While reading");
        temps.push_back(Reading(hour, temperture));
    }
    //end

    cout << "Please enter name of output file: ";
    cin >> name;
    ofstream ost(name.c_str());
    if (!ost) error("can't open output file ", name);  

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i)
        ost << '(' << temps[i].hour << ','
        << temps[i].temperature << ")\n";
    // output result to console window... modification by me!
    for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i)
        cout << '(' << temps[i].hour << ','
        << temps[i].temperature << ")\n";

    keep_window_open("quit");

    return 0;
}
```

//// end

by the way.. you have to formatting the input file like this:

1 60.6
2 45.5
3 70.5

and the output file will be:
(1,60.6)
(2,45.5)
.....
and so one.
Thank you guys for helping me!!!

Comment: Do you mean that you moved the _output_ stream construction to after the `while` loop? I can't see any reason for that to have made a difference.

Comment: yes sir, there is no any technical reason for that but just for making some clear when reading the code between first file name input and second input.

Comment: Right. By posting it as an answer you seemed to be claiming that it solved your problem.

Comment: But you just said there is no reason for this to be the solution and it was just for clarity. So, which is it?